# Simplify the trigonometric equation using double angle and compound angles.

Tags: trigonometry

**Simplify the trigonometric equation $\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ where $t=\tan\dfrac{x}{2}$.**

using double angle and compound angles.

I've worked up to the point where I converted the equation into $\sec$ form after substituting the $\tan\dfrac{x}{2}$. But I'm stuck, so can someone show me how its done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=\frac{1-\tan^2\frac x2}{1+\tan^2\frac x2}=\frac{\cos^2\frac x2-\sin^2\frac x2}{\cos^2\frac x2+\sin^2\frac x2}$$ multipling the numerator & the denominator by $\cos^2\frac x2$

$$=\cos^2\frac x2-\sin^2\frac x2=\cos x$$ as $\cos2A=\cos^2A-\sin^2A$

Answer (score 2):

Try substituting $\tan \frac X2=\cfrac {\sin \frac X2}{\cos \frac X2}$ and simplifying.

Comment: wouldn't that make it more complicated?

Comment: @RedQueen10101 Sometimes you just have to go with it. Clear the fractions in numerator and denominator and you find you get a straightforward double-angle formula to simplify in the numerator and an even more basic identity will deal with the denominator. Then do the same with $\frac {2t}{1+t^2}$. These identities are both important and useful . You might want to investigate the "Weierstrass Substitution".

Answer (score 1):

In numerator, $1-t^2=1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}=1-\dfrac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}$

EDIT: Hover over gray part for further hint:

> $1-\dfrac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}= \dfrac{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}=\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}}$
>  Then, $\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos^2\frac{x}{2}\sec^2\frac{x}{2}}=\cos x$  since $\sec = \dfrac{1}{\cos}$

Comment: Yes, I see what you did there. But how can you simplify further? considering the denominator is sec^2 x/2

Comment: Hey, I would like to ask how do you do the formatting for the maths symbols?

Comment: the final answer is cosX... how do you get that?

Comment: you can click on "edit" option given on each post and see that. i usually whenever encounter some different formatting, i just do the same and remember it for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

There is the identity $\tan(x/2)=\sin(x)/(1+\cos(x)).$ Plug that in, using $s=\sin x,c=\cos x.$ You get after clearing fractions on top and bottom:
$$\frac{(1+c)^2-s^2}{(1+c)^2+s^2}.$$
Here the bottom is $1+2c+c^2+s^2=2c+2$ on applying $s^2+c^2=1$, while the top is $$1+2c+c^2-s^2=1+2c+2c^2-(c^2+s^2) \\ =2c+2c^2=c(2c+2).$$
So the whole expression boils down to just $c$, i.e. it simplifies to $\cos(x)$.